# Swaping the in-app alertview notification with the banner view when using Parse Push

Tags: ios, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I was wondering if there is a way to swap out the `alertview` style notification that happens when a user is inside the app when the notification occurs, to the `banner` notification style (which one would get if *another* app is active while receiving the push).

I am using the [recommended](https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications) Parse Push Notifications configuration as the following, but am unsure where I could make these changes (or that if its possible) - thanks for your help!

```
//In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
[application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];

//In appDelegate.m
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)newDeviceToken {
    // Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.

    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:newDeviceToken];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can change it. You'd need to do it yourself and show your own view...

Comment: Thanks @Wain, when you say "show my own view", do you mean if there is a way to remove the alert view based push notification (when in app) so its just the banner, badge and notifications that show on the lock screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You need to create and configure your own view and display it (explicitly add and remove it as a subview when you want is on and off screen). This means not calling `handlePush:` and instead running your own code to display your own view.